# jQuery: How to select elements of form whose corresponding button has been clicked?

Tags: jquery

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/9kKXX/20/

**My jQuery function**

```
$(function() {
    $('form input[type="text"]').live('keyup', function() {
        var val = $.trim(this.value);
        $('form .create-playlist-button').prop('disabled', val.length == 0).click(function(){
            alert('ALERT TITLE HERE');
          });
    });
});​
```

**Requirement**

- Click on dropdown -> enter text -> hit create
  I would like to select the corresponding form elements like title, views etc. This is not happening right now
- When I click on create, it keeps on alerting again and again, how can I avoid that?

I am very new to jQuery and read couple of places but did not find the solution to it

Thank you

**UPDATE**
**------------**

Answer by Jeff works in fiddle, but when I put that on my code, it does nothing on click. I put the entire code sample in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rDe9V/  , please help me understand what shall have been wrong here

Comment: What have you tried so far? Per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) "the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them".

Comment: This update looks like a completely different code base and a completely different problem. You should close this question out and ask a new one with the separate problem. Asking multiple questions doesnt fit the StackOverflow format very well.

Comment: The new fiddle isnt working because you didnt include the jQuery plugin for `$.fn.slides()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things going on here. [Here is the final fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vueTC/1/).

**First**, You are binding the click event **every time** the key up event is fired. That means the alert will fire at least once for every character in the playlist title. You need to bind the click even on document ready.

```
$(function() {
    $('form input[type="text"]').live('keyup', function() {
        var val = $.trim(this.value);
        $('form .create-playlist-button').prop('disabled', val.length == 0)
    });
    $('form .create-playlist-button').click(function(){
        alert('ALERT TITLE HERE');
    });
});​
```

**Second**, You are using duplicate ids. There are many elements on the page with

```
<div id="video-detail">
```

IDs must be unique. You should change these to classes instead.

```
<div class="video-detail">
```

**Third**, you can access the title by traversing up the DOM tree to a common ancestor between the clicked button and the title the traverse back down to the title. Assuming you change the IDs to classes, that would look like this:

```
$('form .create-playlist-button').click(function(e){
    var title = $(e.target).closest('.video-detail').find('.title').text();
    alert(title);
});
```

You can go to [my fiddle to see the final product](http://jsfiddle.net/vueTC/1/).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @Jeff, it really works on Fiddle, but something not right in my js file, can you please spot that? what happens now it when I do click nothing happens. Here is that fiddle for that - http://jsfiddle.net/rDe9V/

Answer (score 0):

I cannot post a comment because of my reputation, but the new problem is that you are searching for a `class` instead of an `id`.

Your code:

```
$('.item').live('click', function(){
    // alert(this.id);
    var url = $('#video-frame').attr('src');
    var new_url = url.replace(/embed\/[\w -]*/g, 'embed/' + this.id);
    $('#video-frame').attr('src', new_url);
});
```

The correct code (first line):

```
$('#item').live('click', function(){
    // alert(this.id);
    var url = $('#video-frame').attr('src');
    var new_url = url.replace(/embed\/[\w -]*/g, 'embed/' + this.id);
    $('#video-frame').attr('src', new_url);
});
```

Comment: You are right, but it's still an error! You must understand the difference between `id` and `class` in the JQuery selector.